# Rails: path by controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I use Rails 3.2. How can I get the path which will point to GET action only just having controller and action?

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. What have you tried? What do you have in your config/routes.rb file?

Comment: I tried `url_for(controller: 'users', action: 'create')` which returns me `/users`, but it should return nil or raise because I need a path which I can get only with **GET** method

Comment: `create` is for POST. Do you have `resources :users` in your routes file? If you're looking for the GET action for creating a new user, you can use `new_user_url`, or url_for(controller: 'users', action: 'new'). Otherwise, I guess I'm not understanding what you're needing.

Comment: That won't do. I have only controller and action as inputs and need to get GET pathes as output